# Is it possible to add a custom textmarker in Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, delphi

In Delphi there exists the shortcut `Ctrl+Shift+Number` to set a marker ([bookmark](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Using_Bookmarks)) in the IDE to quickly jump to a location (by `Ctrl+Number`).

In my Eclipse IDE (Juno), there exists a shortcut  to jump to a line number (`Ctrl+L`). But does there exist a similar option to jump between self defined markers in the editor like in Delphi?

Comment: Check [`this`](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-37-3b.htm?cp=0_1_0_13).

Comment: Thanks, this helps me. However, in my IDE the bookmarks view is hidden under `Window > Show View > Other > General > Bookmarks`

Comment: @TLama You should make this an answer. Without shortcuts not as simple as in Delphi but useful nevertheless.

Comment: I have found a possible duplicate (though I'm not sure if the accepted answer applies to Juno as well).

Comment: @TLama Missed that one. Yes the answer applies to Juno as well (didn't try the plugin though). I defined `Ctrl+Shift+1` for `Add Bookmark` and `Ctrl+1` for `Show View (Bookmark)`. That comes pretty close.